# C# generating random double number range

Tags: c#

Hi how can i generate a range of "double" numbers? For example how can i generate numbers between 2.50 and 7.20
There is a method in Random() class for "int" numbers Next(Int32, Int32) is there something similar for double?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write an extension method to Random for Random.NextDouble(double MinValue,double MaxValue) so that you can use it everywhere:

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static double NextDouble(this Random RandGenerator, double MinValue, double MaxValue)
    {
        return RandGenerator.NextDouble() * (MaxValue - MinValue) + MinValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Get a value from 0 to 1, then multiply it by `7.20 - 2.50` and add `2.50`.

```
double result = (random.NextDouble() * (7.2 - 2.5)) + 2.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called `Random.NextDouble()`. This returns a `double` between 0 and 1.

```
var value = lower + (random.NextDouble() * (upper - lower))
```

will return what you need.